# Firefox not allowing multiple downloads

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is it possible to allow multiple downloads of files from a single website in firefox like in chrome?

In chromium there was option to allow multiple downloads but in firefox there is no such option in either settings or in address bar

i m trying to do this by writing a javascript code which open new tab with ddl link to download it. Also fetch dont work as that link only allow download when opened in tab in a browser . Also window.open dont work too as it is just opening those sites but not able to download it.

```
const fun=(url)=>{
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", url);
    a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    a.setAttribute("rel", "noopener noreferrer");
  
    
    a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { ctrlKey: true }));
 
 }
 
 const urls=[] // ...list of DDL urls
 
 for(let url of urls)
 {
    fun(url)
 }
```

I tried using `window.open(url, "_blank")` but it is not downloading , just opening homepage of site. I tried unchecking 'Block popups on windows' too but still not working. I need to find a way to allow multiple download just like in chrome.

Edit: These DDL links are protected by CORS as download only starts when is from same origin so thats why fetch dont work. When i m using window.open then instead of downloading it is redirecting to homepage.

Comment: did you consider that a content coming from an http response should have the proper [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header set for the browser to decide its faith as a downladable content? I wonder how the same scenario would be fulfilled by Chrome/Chromium.. are you saying that the same page behaves differently?

Comment: otherwise you should use the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download) attribute on the anchor to instruct the browser it should be downloaded and not just shown

Comment: first there is syntax error in your snippet ( line: `const urls=[...list of DDL urls]`). You havn't set download attribute of anchor tag otherwise it won't work. chrome might have started download because it could not render that file in browser thus falling back to download option.

Comment: @DiegoD When using anchor tag it is downloading even when not using download attribute it but problem is that after 1st download it stops and rest of downloads are not starting which is not the case in the chromium browser as we have option to 'allow multiple downloads' in the right side of the address bar.

Comment: @bogdanoff It is downloading when anchor tag is used but only able to work for single url, not the other ones